# How to change zoomType status in Highchart?

Tags: highcharts, zooming

In my code, I am loading many files during navigation of chart but i want to include feathure like zoomType and hover and mousever on some specific files.  For example, i am changing zoomType='x' of chart by reading sample.json file.

```
 $(function() {
        var chart;
        var options = {
                chart : {
                        type : 'polygon',
                        renderTo : 'container',
                        zoomType:''
                },
                title : {

                        text : ''
                },
                 credits: {
            enabled: false
        }, 



           $.getJSON('sample.json', function(data) {
               options.series=data;
               options.chart.zoomType='x';  /*including zoom feature only for sample.json file*/ 
               var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
          });
```

But this code does not work. How can i fix this error?

Comment: what, pray tell, is your error. Or shall we deduce it by mentally debugging your code!

Comment: what do you mean to change zoomtype??

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See the working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qzsmLAfKuTPo61pDU2hn?p=preview)

I am setting 'x' for default series and zoomtype 'y' for next json data (when you click plus icon), see your previous code and demo at plunker link

```
  $("#container").html("<div style='style:margin:0 auto'>Loading Data</div>") ;
  $.getJSON('data10.json', function(data) {
    options.series=data;
    options.chart.zoomType='x'; 
     chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);


});
```